# Visual C++ thread safety of free and malloc?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, thread-safety, malloc

Does anyone know if free and malloc are threadsafe on visual C++ 2010?

I have having bizarre problems where memory is getting corrupted and im pretty much down to this being the only possiblity.

Does anyone know if the safety can be turned on and off and how?

Comment: I fairly confident it is - I'm assuming you're linking to the multi-threaded runtime.

Comment: Why are you using malloc and free in a C++ program ?

Comment: Because its called visual C++ but it can also compile C.

Comment: @Nick D: the answer you refer to is for Linux/POSIX systems. Visual C++ does not target POSIX systems at all.

Comment: apparently in visual C++ all stdlib and stdio are thread safe, so long as you use the /MD compiler directive to use the multithread libraries. I tried to write colliding code but it would never collide and behaved the same when I added semaphores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you're linking with [thread-safe libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) and using the correct flags, yes, `malloc` should be thread-safe.

If you think otherwise, you should post some code for us to examine.

I should mention that, in the vast majority of cases, it's never the libraries (which have been tested by uncounted millions of people). It's almost *always* your own code which, if you're thorough, has been tested by at most several dozen :-)

Not to say Microsoft (or any other large software house) doesn't ship bugs, just that they'd be discovered and fixed pretty damn quick.

Comment: You were right, I tracked the problem down to a thread switch in critical section.