# malloc()/free() in several threads crashes on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, crash, malloc

Simple code (below, `malloc()`/`free()` sequence being run in 100 threads) crashes on any Windows OS I tried it to run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe using some compiler directive can help?

We build the executable in VS2017 in Release/x64; the executable file crashes on any Windows platform I tried after several minutes of running.

I tried building with VS2015 as well but it doesn't help.

The same code on Linux works fine.

Actually, problem is more serious than it looks; we faced the situation when our server code crashes several times a day in a production environment without any reason (when user calls' number exceeds a certain value). We tried to nail down 
the issue and created simplest solution that reproduces the problem.

Archive with VS project is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A9NC52glqnIsaGLUxNgF6d1xJZRo-77e).

VS says that command line is:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl 
/Fd"x64\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG"
/D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd
/Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\MallocTest.pch"
```

**Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_THREADS 100

void task(void) {
    while (true) {
        char *buffer;
        buffer = (char *)malloc(4096);
        if (buffer == NULL) {
            cout << "malloc error" << endl;
        }
        free(buffer);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    thread some_threads[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        some_threads[i] = thread(task);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        some_threads[i].join();
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you linking with a thread-safe version of the runtime library?

Comment: Which version of the CRT are you using? You should paste the exact compiler and linker command line.

Comment: @ Mike Vine

I posted VS project archive here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A9NC52glqnIsaGLUxNgF6d1xJZRo-77e

VS says that command line is:

/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\MallocTest.pch"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C++ thread safety of free and malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826479/visual-c-thread-safety-of-free-and-malloc)

Comment: @molbdnilo "Are you linking with a thread-safe version of the runtime library?" 

I guess yes because there is /MD flag in command line:  /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\MallocTest.pch"

Comment: Do you get a crash if you use new/delete instead?

Comment: Does it work with a smaller number of threads? Is 100 your magic limit?

Comment: @stijn "Possible duplicate of Visual C++ thread safety of free and malloc?"

Looks similar; ome of replyes is "apparently in visual C++ all stdlib and stdio are thread safe, so long as you use the /MD compiler directive to use the multithread libraries.". I use  /MD and my code is pretty simple but I'm still having problems on Windows.

Comment: You forgot to mention what kind of crash it is.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Error happens even if `new` is used (it actually still calls the same `_malloc_base`). Callstack ends with `ntdll.dll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext(); tdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal(); ucrtbase.dll!_malloc_base()`

Comment: @molbdnilo "Does it work with a smaller number of threads? Is 100 your magic limit?" It definitely crashes on 100 threads; I don't know actual magic number, may be it depends on hardware. In production environment we often have thousands of threads.

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826479/visual-c-thread-safety-of-free-and-malloc. I could reproduce this using the multithreaded crt (BTW on my VS2017 there is no single thread crt at all). It's a crash in ntdll, call stack: `ntdll.dll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext(); tdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal(); ucrtbase.dll!_malloc_base()`

Comment: I could not repro on VS2013, so it could be a new issue in VS. Of course it could also be a complete coincidence that I have failed to crash it.

Comment: @AndersK. new/delete pair crashes as well.

Comment: I enclosed both the `malloc` and the `free` into a critical section and now it apparenty doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: @molbdnilo crashes on my machine with 1000 threads on VC2017, Release x64.
Note: Malloc is threadsafe according to the documentation.
Digging into the asm might reveal more information.

Comment: See my previous comment: It has been running now for >15 minutes without crashing but the computer becomes more and more painful to use, now every 10 to 15 seconds the whole computer becomes unresponsive for a couple of seconds, even the mouse cursor won't move anymore. It looks like a MS bug to me.

Comment: You made my day. Reproduced issue with VC2017 100 threads. It shows access violation in HeapAlloc (somewhere in ntdll.dll)... There is some stupid error... or you've found bug in MS c++ or ms windows...

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong in this code provided that `malloc` and `free` are thread safe which they should be (usage of `/MD` switch).

Comment: @ Michael Walz " and now it apparenty doesn't crash " - Could you please put your code here, in comments?

Comment: @peterg This is the modified code that works. https://pastebin.com/wAWxCCeN. It's just an experience, the code is very poor.

Comment: @peterg.  I was able to reproduce issue with HeapAlloc and private LFH heap on Windows 10.  I'm using similar code, but written mostly on Win32 calls to reduce influence of c++\c. So this is 99.9% bug in Windows 10!!!  Could you please confirm that your problem reproducible on windows server?

Comment: @PavloK could you post that code somewhere, for example on pasebin.com?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Here you go. https://pastebin.com/TPDeq7wr.

Comment: @molbdnilo "You forgot to mention what kind of crash it is" - it's APPCRASH, details:   Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:APPCRASH
  Fault Module Name: StackHash_e3c2
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.17031
  Fault Module Timestamp: 530895af
  Exception Code: c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_24_FROM_ntdll+0x000000000009B13A
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: e3c2
  Additional Information 2: e3c2bb91516b405e48fec31ed1cb5192
  Additional Information 3: b92e
  Additional Information 4: b92ebbb6dbf28e28f6b2b620a162a1f4

Comment: @PavloK Yes, it is reproduced on Windows Server as well.

Comment: @peterg. What version of windows server? I guess this issue has to be reported to MS. Maybe they can provide workaround or tell what's wrong... Would you do a honors and communicate that problem?

Comment: @PavloK It definitely fails on Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012R2.
"I guess this issue has to be reported to MS" - yes, I reported it via support channel but I have only MSDN subscription support level. They told me that this support level accepts issues only when MSDN sample code doesn't work, and my code is self-written.
If you suggets me some MS channel to report the issue I would be grateful.

Comment: I think it make sense post this issue on microsoft technet. I don't expect quick turnaround in this case, but it can work. IMO it sounds like a great potential problem for MS server platform. I think it makes sense to include my research results since they localize problem to core windows functions. Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: @PavloK "I think it make sense post this issue on microsoft technet." - what  forum would you consider the best for issue like this? I didn't find suitable category - all categories about products, not about development: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/newthread
Or would you suggets some other way for reporting on TechNet?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I see dev questions in category Windows Servers... However I support your concern. You can also try social.msdn.microsoft.com.

Comment: @peterg Could you please share link to question\discussion on ms forum.

Comment: @PavloK https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40ccd599-e386-471f-95ce-721a5e80648b/mallocfree-in-several-threads-crahes-on-windows-whats-wrong?forum=winservercore

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63e75495-245b-43eb-8e03-e629573ee079/mallocfree-in-several-threads-crahes-on-windows-whats-wrong?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Posted issue to MS sites,   @PavloK https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/40ccd599-e386-471f-95ce-721a5e80648b/mallocfree-in-several-threads-crahes-on-windows-whats-wrong?forum=winservercore

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63e75495-245b-43eb-8e03-e629573ee079/mallocfree-in-several-threads-crahes-on-windows-whats-wrong?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: All threads share the same heap, access to the allocator/deallocator must be synchronized.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with the Windows Low Fragmentation Heap. It was fixed in OS build 19041 (the May 2020 update).

Comment: Do you have any reference to a KB article, bug id, or anything similar?  A similar test program still crashes in 2022 on Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows Server 2016 with the latest updates installed...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I got this information from a MS engineer in the MSVC STL Discord server after this SO thread was posted here. If it's still broken in WS2012 and WS2016, I imagine it's because the fix never got serviced to these versions, but it should work in WS2022.

Comment: Thanks!  According to my tests it works with WS2008 and with WS2019 (I haven't had a chance to try WS2022).
The thing is, our customer has several virtualized WS2016s and we keep getting 0xC0000374 (heap corruption) app crashes, and we think that this bug is a possible cause. (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your remarkably small MVCE indicates a programming error, `malloc()` and `free()` are supposed to be thread safe and so should the methods invoked on `cout`. The program is not designed to ever stop, so it appears to be a fine stress test for `malloc()` in a multi-thread context.

Note however that if `malloc()` fails, it is questionable to try and report the error to `cout`, which might make further calls to `malloc()` for buffering. Reporting the error to `cerr` or making `cout` unbuffered is advisable. In any case `malloc()` failure should not cause a crash, even in the stream methods.

It looks like you found a bug in the runtime library you link to on the VS target platform. It would be interesting to track the memory usage of the program up to the crash. A steady increase in memory usage would indicate some problems in the runtime library too. The program never allocates more than `MAX_THREADS` blocks of 4K at a time, so the memory use should remain quite low, below 2MB, including the overhead associated with the thread based caches used by modern implementations of `malloc()`.